# QGIS Zonal Statistics

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I have used and FAO raster file for e.g., suitability for agriculture and I calculate zonal statistics at the NUTS 2 level. However, given the fact that the cell size of each cell is not the same everywhere on the map (e.g., smaller cells for more northern cells), I am not sure if the zonal statistics package takes this into account and calculates e.g., the means, weighting by these sizes.

Can someone give me feedback as to whether this happens or not?

Answer (score 1):

The [Zonal statistics tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=zonal%20statistic#zonal-statistics) is not aware that your pixels are different sizes. If vector data and raster data are in the same projection, there should be no problems - only the necessary pixels will get into the statistics.

Comment: Thanks this is helpul. Meaning that to account for differences in size of the cells, would I need to prject both files under an equal area projection? Or is there a weighting option in the zonal statistic package where I can weight by size of the cell?

Comment: @Anastasia Yes, you need to reproject the raster and vector data.